# Connecting to ItsHidden in Ubuntu 9.10 problems

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, troubleshooting, vpn, networkmanager

I try to setup a VPN connection to ItsHidden on Ubuntu 9.10. I double-checked my credentials in the VPN configuration, but I don't think that this is problem. In my syslog I got these messages:

```
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:   Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:   VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 4502
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:   VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' just appeared, activating connections
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin state changed: 1
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin state changed: 3
Jan 11 14:38:46  pppd[4506]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:   VPN connection 'ItsHidden' (Connect) reply received.
Jan 11 14:38:46  pppd[4506]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 11 14:38:46  pppd[4506]: Using interface ppp0
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jan 11 14:38:46  NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 11 14:38:46  pppd[4506]: Connect: ppp0  /dev/pts/1
Jan 11 14:39:06  pptp[4508]: nm-pptp-service-4502 fatal[get_ip_address:pptp.c:430]: gethostbyname 'vpn.itshidden.com': HOST NOT FOUND
Jan 11 14:39:06  pppd[4506]: Modem hangup
Jan 11 14:39:06  pppd[4506]: Connection terminated.
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin failed: 1
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jan 11 14:39:06  pppd[4506]: Exit.
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin failed: 1
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin failed: 1
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin state changed: 6
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   connection_state_changed(): Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Jan 11 14:39:06  NetworkManager:   Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for routing and DNS.
Jan 11 14:39:19  NetworkManager:  [1263213559.003098] ensure_killed(): waiting for vpn service pid 4502 to exit
Jan 11 14:39:19  NetworkManager:  [1263213559.003289] ensure_killed(): vpn service pid 4502 cleaned up
```

Because the gethostbyname is failing, I suppose that the NetworkManager doesn't know that I use proxies for accessing Internet. I'm not sure that this is the real problem.

Could you tell me a solution to make gesthostbyname not failing anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using proxies shouldn't make a difference in your ability to perform dns lookups.  Try running `nslookup vpn.itshidden.com` to check that.  You need to sort out your ability to perform dns lookups (see /etc/resolv.conf) or add vpn.itshidden.com to /etc/hosts and hope the ip address doesn't change or just use the ip address of vpn.itshidden.com in your vpn settings.

Comment: Thank's for the prompt answer.
nslookup vpn.itshidden.com is not working. I receive connection time out. If I change the ip address of vpn.itshidden.com in syslog the connection will time-out. I added the server's name in /etc/hosts, still nothing changed. Could you suggest me other solutions?

Comment: I suspect you have more basic networking problems than setting up the VPN.  Do you have any internet access at all?

Comment: Yes, but only with proxies (I put them on Network Proxy, so they should be accessed globally). I live in a campus so it is possible that some protocols used by nslookup to be restricted.

Comment: If you can only connect to the outside world using proxies and don't even have a working name server you can access then you aren't going to be able to use pptp VPN.  The restrictions blocking outgoing access without a proxy will block pptp an you can't connect to a pptp server using a proxy.